# Shuffling a 5 element array to get an individual order each time C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have an array `int machine[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` and I'm trying to figure out a way to effectively shuffle the array so a unique combination can be read.
The idea is that a different order feeds itself into a *CRAFT* program.
Thank you

Comment: Sometime I feel a "Sunday Evening Emergency Homework Service" might be promising business idea ...

Comment: If you didn't pay enough attention in class, your favorite search engine is better to start with than posting here.

Comment: It's not for homework/class, I'm using a random number gen to change the index's currently, but I cant get it to shuffle the array properly so there's a unique combination every time

Comment: If you are struggling with some particular code, why not dare to share it with us? That's what SO is intended for.

Comment: If you want a **unique** order each time I suggest you permute the array.

Comment: The best way to _figure out_ something is to learn the basics **first**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a simple shuffle program which you can extend to your needs.

`void swap_2_elements(int *m)`  -  randomly swaps 2 elements in the array.

`void swap_2_elements_n_times(int *m, int ntimes)` - swaps 2 randomly chosen elements ntimes using the above function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void swap_2_elements(int *m)
{
  int i1; // random index 1
  int i2; // random index 2
  int v1; // value under undex i1
  int v2; // value under undex i2

  while(1)
  {
      i1 = rand()%5;
      i2 = rand()%5;

      if (i1!=i2) break;
  }

  v1 = m[i1]; 
  v2 = m[i2];

  m[i1] = v2;
  m[i2] = v1;
}

void swap_2_elements_n_times(int *m, int ntimes)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0; i < ntimes; i++)
    swap_2_elements(m);
}

// print table
void print_machine(int *m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
      printf(" i=%i ", m[i]);

      printf("\n");
}

void remember_last_array(int *m1, int *m2)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
         m1[i] = m2[i];
}

int are_arrays_same(int *m1, int *m2)
{
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
         if(m1[i] != m2[i])
         return 0; // no
   }

    return 1; // yes 
}

int main()
 {
  int i;
  int machine1[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
  int machine2[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 

  // Print 10 sets:
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) // each next set is different than the previous one, but it may repeat later!
  {
    while(1)
    {
        swap_2_elements_n_times(machine2,6);   // swap two elements 6 times in the table machine
        if( are_arrays_same(machine1, machine2) == 1 ) // compare with the previous set
            continue; // sets are the same!

        remember_last_array(machine1,machine2);
        break; // set is different from previous one
    }

    print_machine(machine1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 i=1  i=5  i=4  i=3  i=2 
 i=2  i=5  i=3  i=4  i=1 
 i=4  i=1  i=2  i=5  i=3 
 i=5  i=1  i=3  i=4  i=2 
 i=3  i=1  i=4  i=5  i=2 
 i=4  i=5  i=1  i=2  i=3 
 i=5  i=4  i=1  i=3  i=2 
 i=4  i=2  i=3  i=5  i=1 
 i=3  i=4  i=1  i=2  i=5 
 i=3  i=4  i=5  i=1  i=2
```

Comment: You're not initializing the random number generator so you get the same order every run.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That is correct. I do not.